# CakePHP renders HTML email with <p> tags at every new line

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, html-email

Here is the cake code..... notice the `$email_body`

```
<?php
$this->Email->reset();
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'port'=>'465', 
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username'=>'noreply@example.com',
    'password'=>'a_password_you_cant_see',
);
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
$this->Email->template = 'default';
$this->Email->from = '"NO-REPLY" <noreply@example.com>';
$this->Email->to = "rakib@example.com";
$this->Email->subject = "test PHP html email";
$email_body = "Hello message body
                <hr />
                This is rakib
                <br />
                <table width=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"#ff0\">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            In a table
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>";
$this->Email->send($email_body);
?>
```

---

After sending this email out, when I view the Original mail contents via the `Show Original` button from GMail's drop down menu [at top-right corner of an email], here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<!-- Starting to render - email/html/default -->
<p> Hello message body</p>
<p>                         <hr /></p>
<p>                         This is rakib</p>
<p>                         <br /></p>
<p>                         <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ff0"></p>
<p>                             <tr></p>
<p>                                 <td></p>
<p>                                     In a table</p>
<p>                                 </td></p>
<p>                             </tr></p>
<p>                         </table></p>
<p> </p>
<!-- Finished - email/html/default -->
```

---

`<p>` and `</p>` tags got included at EVERY new line..... why is that? Using CakePHP 1.3

Answer (score 2):

When doing anything with emails, try and stick to the MVC principles. By writing your email's HTML (view) in what is likely to be a controller can make things a little messy and tends to bloat your code (e.g. composing markup in your controller).

Use templates to author the structure of your email and then use view variables (`$this->set(...)`) to apply specific values to it (See [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Email.html#controller-code-for-using-email-component)).

I'm afraid I don't know why `<p>` tags are being inserted but I suspect it has got something to do with the newline character `\n` which is implicitly inserted each time you hit the return key.

In summary, move your markup to the template and everything should be better.

Comment: I explained the cause of the `<p>` tags in my answer, but your suggestions on *how* the OP should send e-mails (using templates) is spot-on!

Comment: well..... i typed the html of the `$email_body` here for example. In my actual project, I am actually rendering a view which is being shown on the browser and then I am loading that same rendered view into a variable and mailing that to the recipients behind the scene. I already designed a view template for the browser. I didn't want to recreate the same view template for another email template. The cause of the <p> tag is explained by @thaJeztah

Answer (score 2):

If you're directly setting the body of the email, CakePHP expects the text passed to be *plain text*.

By setting the type of email to HTML (`Email->sendAs = 'html'`), CakePHP will create a HTML version of your plain-text body by converting new-lines to `<p>` tags

In your case, you pass HTML as message body, but CakePHP assumes it is plain-text, therefore converts new lines to `<p>` tags as well

Read the documentation here: [Sending a basic message](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Email.html#sending-a-basic-message)

### note

Although this should explain your *question*, please look at the answer that Sam provided as that will give you an answer on how you *should* send an HTML email!

Comment: thanks @thaJeztah ... that explains why i was facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this... I needed to create my own `default.ctp` file in my app folder at `app/views/elements/email/html/default.ctp` and put the following in the file

```
<?php
echo $content;
```

That solved my problem. Please look below for the analysis of this problem.

*[P.S. I did the same thing for `app/views/elements/email/text/default.ctp` for text based mails to print correctly]*

---

***The problem was that***, since i didn't declare any `default.ctp` element in my own app folder, cake was falling back to the view element in its own core lib folder at `cake/libs/view/elements/email/html/default.ctp` . Over there, this is what it does.

```
<?php
$content = explode("\n", $content);
foreach ($content as $line):
    echo '<p> ' . $line . "</p>\n";
endforeach;
?>
```

That's where the `<p>` tags were coming from at every new line. Thanks to [@thaJeztah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125590/636762). In order to avoid this from happening, i needed to create my own `default.ctp` element in my app folder that would eventually override the `default.ctp` element in the core's lib folder.

That's one bad case scenario.